# No QGIS data provider plugins found

Tags: plugins, qgis

I installed QGIS via OSGeo4 installation. I verified that the vector and raster data providers are working (i have my own application that use the QGIS lib to display maps). However, when I tried to launch QGIS itself, it works except that it always complains No QGIS data provider plugins are found in C:\OSGeo4W64\plugins. I don't know where it gets that path as the necessary libs seem already in the apps\qgis\plugins folder. I've tried to set the QGIS_PLUGINPATH etc to no avail. So, my question is that how to "redirect" QGIS to look at the right place for gis plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the qgis-bin.exe, but instead should run the qgis.bat for launching QGIS